# Possible to loop through tables in mySQL (using PHP) with table name containing a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web-applications, phpmyadmin

I'm pretty new to programming and trying to design a web application which provides a front-end to update data for an online course database (tables incl. users, assignments, questions, answers, etc). All data is coming into this database upon submission via course management system. Currently working with dummy data for development purposes.

The idea is to allow a user to update from the front end, rather than have updates occur automatically from the back end (as in using triggers). This is because we have a relatively small data set, and will just need the updated tables for users not familiar with mysql to export into data analysis programs.

Using multiple joins, I've created a list of assignments already taken by users, which looks like this:

```
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| id | assignment_id | quiz_name                             |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 |             2 | Guidance Counselors (Post-Assessment) |
|  2 |             3 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment)  |
|  3 |             4 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment)  |
+----+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

In PHP, I've coded a basic front-end for displaying and updating these assignments in a multi-selection dropdown, which looks like this:

[Assignment list table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0cqt.jpg)

Whenever a user wants to update the list, php runs this if statement (the same one used to generate the above table):

```
  //update assignment list when button is clicked
  if(isset($_POST['updatelist'])){
  //query to update the assignment list
  $sql_update = "DELETE FROM assignment_list;";
  $sql_update .= "TRUNCATE assignment_list;";
  $sql_update .= "INSERT INTO assignment_list....
  #values added from joined assignment, quizzes, and user_quizzes tables
  SELECT...
  INNER JOIN ...
  INNER JOIN ...
   ...
  GROUP BY assignment_id";

      $update_result = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql_update);

      //success and error messages here

    }
```

ETA: Which is then reflected in the dropdown menu. This menu then should allow users to select one or more assignments for which to update data, let's say if there are new user submissions and scores available for that assignment (i.e. the data contained within each assignment -- structurally they are all the same).

Updating the list seems to be working, but I am struggling to figure out the best way to update what we're calling "consolidated data" tables (appended with "_(assignment_id)" for each individual assignment. So when a user selects "update data", the data in the table for the selected assignment(s) above should update. As an example, consolidated_data_4 looks like this (some fields omitted for better readability):

```
+------------------+---------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| consolidation_id | user_id | assignment_id | quiz_id | assignment_pass_score_point | assignment_pass_score_perc | quiz_name                            | answer_id |
+------------------+---------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|                1 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175973 |
|                2 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175981 |
|                3 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175985 |
|                4 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175991 |
|                5 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175995 |
|                6 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    175999 |
|                7 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    176002 |
|                8 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    176009 |
|                9 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    176015 |
|               10 |      34 |             4 |      50 |                        5.00 |                      50.00 | Guidance Counselors (Pre-Assessment) |    176021 |
+------------------+---------+---------------+---------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Each table is currently identified by its assignment id, e.g. "consolidated_data_4" is a table in which assignment_id = 4 for every record in that table.

I tried looping through each table (using a foreach loop) and performing a similar query as the one above for the assignments list, but I receive an error unless I separate the queries out like so (also abridged):

```
//for each assignment user selects, start with an empty table and join data from corresponding course database tables

    foreach($_POST['selectassign'] as $assignment){
  $table = "quiz_data_update_application.consolidated_data_".$assignment;
  //query updates consolidated data table(s) for selected assignments
  $sql_del = "DELETE FROM $table";
  $sql_trunc = "TRUNCATE $table";

  //records added from joining tables in course db
  $sql_ins = //sql omitted here for brevity
  ....
  $del_sel_res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_del);
  $trunc_sel_res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_trunc);
  $ins_sel_res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_ins);
}
```

(The only difference between this and the code that doesn't work is that the queries are combined in the same fashion as the first PHP snippet above; this seems redundant to post here).

Using single queries seems inefficient and will slow down the application. I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this than using part of a table name as a variable in PHP loops. (Don't see too many people asking about this or iterating through actual tables as opposed to fields) It seems there's either some silly syntax mistake I'm missing, or mysqli_multiquery() can't be used in loops/is overall a poor approach?

Some of the higher-ups where I am working have suggested either:

(1) creating separate loops - one to temporarily create a new table based on a users' selection of assignments, and another to split that up into separate tables by assignment (this part they are saying is required for optimal data analysis. IMO this makes everything more challenging than having a large "master" table of data for ALL assignments -- which I did in fact have success doing -- but alas this is how they're requesting it be done). Those tables would then be deleted after an update completes;

(2) Using stored procedures. This I am not as familiar with, and not sure how that'd work, but if it's more feasible than (1), I could look into it more.

Any other alternative, more feasible suggestions would be appreciated as well. I've made a lot of progress with this, but have been stuck here the past few weeks and not finding much in the way of online resources.

Apologies for the length of the post. I thought it necessary to provide more context rather than less.

Comment: no need to delete if you are going to use truncate

Comment: multi_query is almost always a bad idea so hard to debug

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why delete and truncate were both used; this was done by a former colleague who was more familiar with mysql than myself, so I figured there was a reason beyond my scope of understanding and left it that way.

Comment: run each query, check it worked, run the next query

Comment: with multi_query, you mean?

Comment: With multi-query it is hard (impossible?) to test if each statement worked.

Answer (score 0):

Single queries is the way to go.  The perceived inefficiency is not there -- the operations are more costly than the `mysqli_query`.

If you have thousands of tables that to work with, then I question the wisdom of having multiple similar tables.  Instead, have an extra column to indicate which thing is involved.

`DELETE` (all of a table) and `TRUNCATE` have virtually the same effect; there is no need to do both.  `TRUNCATE` is faster.

And deleting one indexed row from a table is a lot faster than truncate + insert.

Furthermore, batching the deletes into a single SQL statement is even faster.  So is batch inserting multiple rows at once.  This is easily 10 *times* as fast.

Comment: Batch delete and insert would still involve a similar structure as far as iterating through tables, correct?

I am not sure what you mean by deleting one row, as the issue here is there's no way to detect where new data has been added without utilizing triggers.Thus simply truncating the table and drawing all info from the tables that immediately receive the new information. 

I agree regarding the separate tables; the original plan was to have one large table aggregating all assignments, and selecting by assignment from there.

Comment: @R.J. - If you could explain the flow of data (what causes deletes/inserts, how often, etc), we might be able to get more specific and do less hand-waving.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by what causes deletes/inserts? As I described, queries are run at the discretion of the user in that when they select an "update" option from the front-end, it essentially refreshes the whole table. New data is added from the course system's database via a series of join statements in the insert (application has its own db). This is designed to update data without using triggers. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I don't yet understand why there are multiple tables, nor why you need to loop through them.  Your last Comment sounded more like `UPDATEing` a single row in a single table, then `SELECTing` one whole table.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` might help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

@Rick James here is SHOW CREATE TABLE for one of the tables, although the structure is the same for all of them.

```
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| consolidated_data_2 | CREATE TABLE `consolidated_data_2` (
  `consolidation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quiz_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_pass_score_point` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_pass_score_perc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quiz_name` varchar(3800) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_text` varchar(3800) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `question_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_textA` varchar(800) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_added_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_answer_text` varchar(3800) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_image` varchar(800) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_correct` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct_answer_text` varchar(3800) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`consolidation_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The reason for having multiple tables is so that there's one table unique to each assignment id, so each assignment table can be updated separately/selectively for analysis purposes. 
It isn't necessarily just updating one row, since each assignment is typically 10 questions. So each new user submission would add 10 more rows in most cases.

I am attaching an ER diagram which shows all the tables that have source data for the consolidated data tables.

[ER Diagram for consolidated_data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXpwe.jpg)

(Blue = fields used for joins; yellow = all other fields included in the table; data type info on some for reference)